# Prevent textarea from automatically scrolling when I change cursor position

Tags: javascript, textarea, slatejs

I have a textarea with a lot of text and a vertical scrollbar. When I move the cursor beyond the visible area (imagine having a long document, and then pressing down arrow many times until cursor goes off screen), the browser will automatically scroll the cursor into view, so it always remains visible.

How do I prevent this behavior? I need to be able to move cursor beyond the visible area, without it being autoscrolled.

(technically, it's not a textarea but a React-based text editor, in dom it's a div with content-editable set to true, not sure if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear this is possible. From the spec:

> It MUST be possible to put the caret in any of the Legal Caret
>   Positions programatically and for the caret to be visible in these in
>   any editing host that is in the "events", "caret" or "typing" state.

https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditable.html#caret_positions

"MUST put the caret" & "MUST be visible" indicate this.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Thank you for your reply!